# How can I mysqldump a large database on Windows workstation without it crashing?

Tags: mysql

I have a very large MySQL database (total 2027 files and 4.81gb in mysql/data) which is used for a Drupal site. I have some work to do on this and have downloaded the database to my workstation (to be strictly accurate, I loaded it into a VirtualBox VM running Windows under OS X), successfully loaded it into mysql (so I actually have the site running in the VM, using Acquia DevDesktop to run everything).

I want to backup the database, so do the classic command-line:

```
mysqldump -u drupaluser eco > 20160305-eco.sql
```

Trouble is, the operation causes the mysql server to crash on a very large table. I get the message that mysqldump "lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping" the table at row 3134695.

And indeed, the server is crashed and has to be restarted.

I wondered whether there might be a memory problem so tried with these options:

```
mysqldump -u drupaluser --skip-extended-insert --quick eco > 20160305-eco.sql
```

But this gave me exactly the same error. Has anyone any ideas of mysqldump options that might help me round this?

Comment: How much RAM and disk space are available to your VM? Try giving it more of both. What access method are you using for the large tables (InnoDB, MyISAM)?  Are you running mysqldump on your host machine (your mac) or on the VM? Try running it on the host.

Comment: The Mac has a total of 8Gb RAM, of which nearly 5Gb are allocated to the VM. The database is a mix of MyISAM and InnoDB, with InnoDB being used for the big tables, and in particular for the one where the crash occurred. I'm running mysqldump in the VM - I've no idea how to run it on the Mac against a MySQL database in the VM

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database

Answer (score 0):

Read this for general tips on making mysqldump go fast.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database

Make sure your database is quiet before dumping it. It should not have other active clients running against it.

You already tried `--quick` . It keeps your large innodb tables from blowing out your transaction buffers.

Try giving your VM more disk space. You may be running out.

Dump your tables one at a time, biggest first.

Try running your mysqldump on your mac. Your virtualbox vm has an IP address, something like 192.168.137.100. Read this to learn about finding out this IP address. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36592

Then, on a shell in your mac do this.

```
mysqldump -h 192.168.xxx.xxx -u username -p password etc etc
```

This should connect the mysqldump on your mac to the mysql instance in your vm, and dump the table or tables you mention.